# Why does my keypress handler not work when I use anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I use jQuery for my homepage and add a keylistener when the window is loaded. It looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var debug = $('#debug'); // this is a fixed div I use to print debug
                             // information to the screen
    $(window).keypress(function(event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        debug.text(keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 106 || keyCode == 40)
            nextCard();
        else if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 107)
            prevCard();
    });
});
```

You can jump from one card to another using the arrow up and arrow down key or 'j' and 'k'. It works fine as long the page is loaded without jumping to an anchor. That means when I go to the page like http://www.blah.com it works fine but when I load it like this http://www.blah.com#anchor it doesn't work anymore.

**Update:** $(window).load() gets fired, so this is not the problem.

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does it not work?  Does it not function at all or does it function incorrectly.  If incorrectly, in what way?

Comment: My guess is that the keypress event is actually working just fine, but `nextCard` and `prevCard` are misbehaving in some way.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of the keypress handler, load the page to an anchor, then press a key.  What happens?

Comment: keypress does not work at all. I've updated the code above so that you can see now what "debug" is. When I press a key, the keycode isn't added to the debug div. Therefore the function does not get called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It actually had nothing to do with the keypress handler. It was a handler that initiates a scrolling animation whenever someone enters the page with a hash in the URL.

Nevertheless thanks for making me think about my code :P next time I try to consider such bugs before I post here....

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find an easy solution, you could try to rebind your function everytime when the hash changes. For example with this plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: I've tried the plugin but it seems that it doesn't work with jquery 1.9.1

Comment: if it doestn work with jquery 1.9.1 you should try to also load jquery migration plugin. see jquery website.